# Change PHP grammar

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is a way to change out the grammar of PHP with my own.

For example:

- `print` = `show`
- `class` = `box`
- `function` = `item`

I have read a little about ANTLR but that looks pretty complicated. Wondering if there is a simple way, like a language file?

Comment: Did you mean: *grammar*

Comment: I dont believe there is a simple way... why do you want to do this? Maybe change the parse config file, and recompile PHP with new settings...

Comment: develop php_new or your desired name

Comment: `function = item`? Bad idea. Functions and methods are actions, not things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no simple way. Php keywords are hardcoded in the interpreter and there are no means to change them. So, if you don't like them for some reason, you options are basically:

- edit [the lexer](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l) file and compile your very own php binary
- use a preprocessor that would convert your keywords into valid php on the fly (like http://code.metala.org/p/ccpp/, but it looks rather dead to me)
- use a "better-than-php" language, like [Hack](http://hacklang.org/)
- learn some other programming language
- create your own

or

- just deal with it. Seriously, php is only fun if you enjoy it as is and don't try to make a "better" language out of it.

Comment: +1, but "just deal with it" should also be an option ;)

Comment: the last sentence applies to life itself.